# KeyError: 'The `start` argument could not be matched to a location related to the index of the data.'

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, google-colaboratory

How to solve the following error code!,
Please include the repair code from the code image that I provided

Error Code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyfMT.png)
Error Message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0s90.png)

### Error Message Text

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 1231545600000000000

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
16 frames
KeyError: Timestamp('2009-01-10 00:00:00')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
KeyError: Timestamp('2009-01-10 00:00:00')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
KeyError: Timestamp('2009-01-10 00:00:00')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
KeyError: 'only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/statsmodels/tsa/base/tsa_model.py in get_prediction_index(start, end, nobs, base_index, index, silent, index_none, index_generated, data)
360         )
361     except KeyError:
--> 362         raise KeyError(
363             "The `start` argument could not be matched to a"
364             " location related to the index of the data."

KeyError: 'The `start` argument could not be matched to a location related to the index of the data.'

I hope the code will be like this or there will be additional code,
so that it can be run

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLP7s.png)

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)